# How can I Add My Attribute in Filter Navigation?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, layered-navigation, filter

If you look at the Price Filter in Category. As Price in Not Drop Down Attribute, it's `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` as `Price` & In Admin it dosen't have Drop Down Values.

[image]

Now I have added my Attribute named "Promotion" which is a Text Field. I'm not able to add that as a Filter Navigation.

[image]

So people can Filter Data with my Newly create Attribute. How to solve this?

[image]

I have already Clean the Cache & Indexing also. I would like to show my Promotion Field in Filter Navigation.

**In "Attribute Properties" if i select "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" as "DropDown", then only it works.**

Lastly, have to manage through Database.

Comment: No. its not possible directly, because magento support dropdown, multiselect, or price type for navigation. you can not add directly text field attribute in navigation.

Comment: It Means i have to convert my Text Fields to Dropdown, Multiselect, or Price type? Gonna huge task i have more than 10K SKUs with this Attributes. Ha

Comment: yes. may be. you can wait for some answers.